Using JSON Schema Dependencies for Dynamic Dropdowns in JSON Forms
I'm using JSON Forms to render a field mapping view where users can map/translate a chosen field and its enumeration values to values in another system. The issue is that based on the input of field, I'd like to dynamically populate the fieldMapping.
Input data from system A
const results = [
  {
    label: "Background Color",
    name: "background_color",
    options: [
      { label: "Green", value: "green" },
      { label: "Red", value: "red" },
      { label: "Blue", value: "blue" },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: "Text Color",
    name: "text_color",
    options: [
      { label: "Black", value: "black" },
      { label: "White", value: "white" },
      { label: "Grey", value: "grey" },
    ],
];

I want to use this results array to populate the field dropdown with the name property and dynamically change the available options for fieldMapping based on the selected field.
For example:

If the user selects Background Color in the field dropdown, the fieldMapping section should allow mapping only the values [green, red, blue].
If the user selects Text Color in the field dropdown, the fieldMapping section should allow mapping only the values [black, white, grey].

Here's the JSON schema I'm working on:
const schema = {
  type: "object",
  properties: {
    field: {
      type: "string",
      enum: results.map((r) => r.name), // Dropdown for "background_color", "text_color", etc.
    },
    fieldMapping: {
      type: "array",
      items: {
        type: "object",
        properties: {
          value: { type: "string" },
          mappedValue: { type: "string" },
        },
        required: ["value", "mappedValue"],
      },
    },
  },
  dependencies: {
    field: {
      oneOf: results.map((r) => ({
        properties: {
          field: { enum: [r.name] },
          fieldMapping: {
            type: "array",
            items: {
              type: "object",
              properties: {
                value: {
                  type: "string",
                  enum: r.options.map((o) => o.value), // Dynamically populated enum
                },
                mappedValue: { type: "string" },
              },
              required: ["value", "mappedValue"],
            },
          },
        },
      })),
    },
  },
};

The problem
The field dropdown renders correctly and displays the available fields, but the fieldMapping dropdown for value always displays an input field instead of dynamically showing the appropriate options (enum) for the selected field. It seems like the dependencies or oneOf logic is not being applied correctly.
I’ve verified that the schema is being generated as expected and includes the appropriate enum values for each field. However, JSON Forms does not seem to dynamically update the fieldMapping dropdown when the field changes.
